# Change default Locale language android

Tags: java, android, localization, locale

I have made 2 different strings.xml, 1 for swedish and 1 for english.

**Code for changing Locale**

```
 public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(getContext(), BaseActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

**Onclicklisteners for switching language**

```
swedish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLocale("sv");
        }
    });
    english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setLocale("en");
        }
    });
```

The thing is, the app took it by itself to start the app on swedish, which, as far as I know, haven't set by myself. How do I change the default Locale when the app starts?

**Question**

1. How do I set the app to start with using the english xml?
2. Does anyone have a tip on how to store the choice the user makes? I want it to store if the user presses to use swedish if it closes the app.

Comment: Have you created two differents values folder for it ? `values-sw` and `values-en` and put different `strings.xml` file in to them.

Comment: @Piyush I have 2 different strings.xml in the values folder. I read something about 2 different values folder but I figured it should work by only adding 2 different string files since that's the only change I want.

Comment: No it can't be worked. You must create two different values folders.

Comment: @Piyush OK, so that's why I can't set the default language? Because it works to change it on the click of a button, but I have to change it everytime I open the app.

Comment: Yes. because of that

Comment: @Piyush Ok great, thanks! I will try that. Do I need to add color folder etc. to the swedish values folder aswell or is it enough to only add the relevant files I want to be able to switch?

Comment: No need to add drawable folder. Only put different strings.xml files in different values folder

Answer (score 3):

**It's just for some languages.**

I found when I use translator editor of android studio, to add a locale for example Persian(fa), instead of `values-fa` android studio add `values-fa-rIR`so when we asked for `Locale("fa")` it won't works. So if it doesn't work go to `project view` and rename your folder (for my example `res/values-fa-rIR` to `res/values-fa`).

And `setContentView()` after that,also

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When user press on language selection store this value into prefrence and once you back again then you have already a stored value in prefrence. now just call the method like:- `setLocale_forstartup("en");`

```
`public void setLocale_forstartup(String lang) {

        myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

public void changeLanguage(){
        try {

```
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        // Change locale settings in the app.
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale("en");
        // conf.locale = new Locale("en");
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```