# How to change the default language of Android app?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to make Arabic the default language of my app. I created another string XML for Arabic strings. and here is my code:

```java
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            loadLocale();
    
            Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            setLocale("ar");
    .....
    }
      private void setLocale(String lan) {
            Locale locale = new Locale(lan);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            // save data to shared preferences
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("My_Lang", lan);
            editor.apply();
    
        }
    
        public void loadLocale()
        {
    
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String language = prefs.getString("My_Lang","");
            setLocale(language);
        }
```

but it doesn't work as expected, it is showing English as the default language and after using the app the language changes to Arabic! I want it to be Arabic all the time!!

Comment: Try to change your default language file : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization#creating-defaults

Comment: but then I can't use  setLocale("ar"); right ?

Comment: You can. Another person had the same problem has you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51217026/12554903

Comment: not the same problem, mine is different!